# ReactJS server side async for search engines

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm rendering my website server side with ReactJS + [Router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router)
and many of my components make a REST call to generate content. This content won't be send as HTML server side since it's an async call.

A component which could look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
// Imports omitted

export default class MyPage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {items: []};
            fetch("http://mywebservice.com/items").then((response) => {
                response.json().then((json) => {
                    this.setState({items: json.items})
                }).catch((error) => {});
            });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.items && this.state.items.length > 0) {
            var rows = [];
            // Go through the items and add the element
            this.state.items.forEach((item, i) => {
                rows.push(<div key={item.id}></div>);
            });
            return <div>
                    <table>
                         {rows}
                    </table>
            </div>;
        }
        else {
            return <span>Loading...</span>
        }
    }
}
```

a search engine would index "Loading..." while I obviously want my elements (items) indexed. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout `react-async` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async) or `react-async-render` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-render)

Sounds like it's just what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, I think in order to accomplish that you will need on server side request handler, collect all necessary data and pass it to `ReactDOM.RenderToString()` as initial state JSON string, then create custom `fetch()` which will check if the initial data exists, if yes then it will render html right away.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) is so popular is that it enforces data separation. Ideally, you have a single place where you specify all the data application needs to render. In redux that'll be a store, but let's assume you store all the data in the topmost element's props. If that is the case, all you need to do is to provide all the relevant props to that topmost element and it will render everything nicely. The way to collect all the data needed is up to server though. I would suggest getting clues for that from current url and logged-in user info (be it a token or a cookie).